# How to say "a bit of code"

Tags: synonyms, terminology, register

I am describing how this part of my code works:

```
def store_output(self, file_name, identifier):
    dsc_in = ogr.Open(file_name)
    if dsc_in is None:
        raise Exception("Reading data failed.")
    dsc_out = ogr.Open("PG:" + self.connstr)
    if dsc_out is None:
        raise Exception("Database connection has not been established.")
    layer = dsc_out.CopyLayer(dsc_in.GetLayer(), identifier,
                              ['OVERWRITE=YES',
                               'SCHEMA={}'.format(self.schema_name))
    if layer is None:
        raise Exception("Writing output data to the database failed.")
```

I now want to describe the "if layer is None:" parts, and I am missing a word (or a couple of words):

**"Each of the three above mentioned operations is followed by a simple ______________ that checks if the output of the operation is not None."**

I thought about "statement", but I feel like that's not exactly what it is.

Comment: I would probably say "exception handler," but I feel like this is more of a technical question than an English one.

Comment: You have to assess your audience/context and decide whether a technical term or an informality such as "bit of code" is appropriate.  You could say, for example, "conditional test that raises an exception when applicable"

Comment: In plain English, the "if layer is None" line is a *test*.  You're looking at a simple test that checks whether the output of .CopyLayer is None.

Comment: I would never use "bit" in its informal sense to describe computer code because there is a quite different technical sense used in computer science. I like the "simple test" suggested in the last comment. Alternatively, "short procedure" works.

Comment: Or, shorter, "... followed by a simple test if the output ..."

Comment: Conditional expression. That is the technical term. If you are assigning it to a variable it is a still a conditional expression. It returns true or false. Boolean expression is also optional but I would reserve that for things that manipulate true and false values using boolean operators.

Comment: But I may be very wrong so I will leave it to others to post appropriate answers.

Comment: Btw, what programming language is that? It might help if we know what language's documentation to refer to for a canonical answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// --------------------------
    dsc_in = ogr.Open(...)    // A statement that evaluates an expression (the method) and then assigns its result to a variable.
    if dsc_in is None:        // A conditional statement that evaluates an expression.
        raise Exception()     // A statement.
// --------------------------
    dsc_out = ogr.Open(...)   // Same pattern as above...
    if dsc_out is None:
        raise Exception()
// --------------------------
    layer = dsc_out.Copy(...) // Same pattern as above...
    if layer is None:
        raise Exception()
```

> Each of the three abovementioned operations is followed by a simple _____ that checks if the output of the operation is different from None."

### Some general terms:

- **Statement** - Basically any "line" of code.  *Line* is in quotes because you can technically have a statement span multiple lines.
- **Expression** - Something that is evaluated to produce a value.  This could be a method call, such as in the above code snippet, or even something like "1 + 1".
- **Operation** - A mathematical or binary action.  (+, -, *, /, |, &, etc)

If I could suggest a description of this code snippet, I would say:

> Each of the three aforementioned assignment statements is followed by a test to see whether the assigned value is "none", and if so, an exception is raised.

Answer (score 5):

I would say something like **code block**, **piece of code**, or a more specific description of the statement(s). That is, since "if layer is None" is an if statement, I might say "followed by a simple **if statement**..." with the implied context that I am referring to the entirety of the conditional and the code within it.

Comment: Agreed.  It's an "if statement", common programming jargon.

Comment: Yes, I'd say code block, block of code, or just block.  It's a lot easier discover the usual term if you work with a language that uses something like {} to delimit blocks of code :-)

Answer (score 3):

The part that "checks" is called a (boolean) *condition*:

> In computer science, conditional statements, conditional expressions and conditional constructs are features of a programming language, which perform different computations or actions depending on whether a programmer-specified boolean **condition** evaluates to true or false.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) (emphasis, mine)

Comment: Technically true, but I think the OP is asking for a term to describe the block of code that's executed if the result of logical if statement is true.

Comment: Technically, the *condition* is `(blah) is None`, and the whole if-then-else chunk is the *conditional statement* (or just *conditional* for short).

Comment: @jamesqf Actually, the OP was interested in "a simple ___ that *checks if the output ... is different from None*" (emphasis, mine). The part that gets executed if the statement is true *isn't* the check itself.

Answer (score 2):

Consider also [**guard**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guard), a word for a conditional that emphasizes that some code must be prevented from executing if a condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

I, as someone who's a native English speaker and has been programming professionally for decades, would say... "bit of code" to fill the blank in "Each of the three above mentioned operations is followed by a simple ______________ that checks if the output of the operation is different from None."

Comment: Please read the body of the question and not just the title.

Comment: @Typhon the phrase "bit of code" is what I'd use to fill in the blank.

Comment: alright fair enough, but they are asking for the formal technical term and not just any way to refer to it with English.

Comment: @Typhon I don't see any reference in the Q to a request for a technical term.

Comment: "I feel like that's not **exactly** what it is." (emphasis mine). Clearly a bit of code is considered not specific enough for them, hence they are looking for the technical term. Furthermore they used the tag terminology meaning that they want a technical term.

Comment: @Typhon in all the years that I've been (1) speaking and writing English as a first language -- since the Kennedy Administration -- and (2) professionally writing code -- since Reagan -- a completely valid "technical" term for a bit of code has been... "a bit of code".

Comment: Irregardless, considering they asked the question they are certainly asking for a more specific description of what that piece of code is. Your answer isnt useful at all for them.

Comment: "*Irregardless, considering...*" **Regardless**, @Typhon.  The word is **regardless**.

Comment: Do not dodge the statement altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are overthinking it and should rely on the laziness of programmers:

> Each of the three above mentioned operations is followed by a simple check that the output of the operation is not None.

For the code you posted, this is a very clear description.

In general when you “snip” out a piece of code to look at or use you can call it a “snippet”

Answer (score 0):

a short piece of code, as given in this book on programming: [short piece of code](https://books.google.com/books?id=yJD3847JKPwC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22a%20short%20piece%20of%20code%22%20%2B%20programming&source=bl&ots=ZKQ4wzEZ7P&sig=cZtacYHxVUniKjbfgBq42WsbZ7w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyiNL32K_YAhXIl-AKHRJECVEQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=%22a%20short%20piece%20of%20code%22%20%2B%20programming&f=false)